# Corona - passing lat, long variables to setcenter and addmarker not working

Tags: google-maps, lua, coronasdk

This question is related to passing variable data as map coordinates (lat,long) in Corona (lua) using the map api functions setcenter and addmarker.

I am having trouble getting mapview - setcenter and addmarker to recognize a lat,long variable. Would be grateful to anyone out there that could offer up any suggestions. It's difficult to diagnose since I have to load the apk on the device to test, I'm not able to see the errors.

What Works
This code works just fine on the device:

```
myMap:setCenter( 30.192729,-81.364483 )

local function mapmarker( event )
myMap:addMarker( 30.192729,-81.364483 )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 10000, mapmarker)
```

FYI: I had to add the delay to give the map time to load the marker, otherwise it wouldn't show the marker on the device.

What Doesn't Work
Now if I replace the actual lat, long numbers with variables, it won't work. The mapview still works but it defaults to my current locaction.

```
local currentXlatitude = tonumber(decodedData[2]) 
local currentXlongitude = tonumber(decodedData[3])
local location = (currentXlatitude.."," ..currentXlongitude)
```

1) When I print these variables to the console they are holding valid numbers.

```
print (currentXlatitude)
print (currentXlongitude)
30.192729    
-81.364483
```

2) Additionally, I tested the variables  by passing to a map url and they work fine.
mapURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Hello,!@"..location

3) Just to be sure, I set the variables to actual numbers but that did not work either.

```
local currentXlatitude =  30.192729    
local currentXlongitude = -81.364483
```

4) Here is the code with the variable "location". On the device, the map just defaults to my location, no marker.

```
myMap:setCenter( location )

local function mapmarker( event )
myMap:addMarker( location )
end

timer.performWithDelay( 10000, mapmarker)
```

5) I also tried the following. Same result on the device, defaults to my location.

```
myMap:setCenter( currentXlatitude..","..currentXlongitude)

local function mapmarker( event )
myMap:addMarker( currentXlatitude..","..currentXlongitude)
end

timer.performWithDelay( 10000, mapmarker)
```

6) I've also tried " " and ' ' around the variables.

7) One last thing, I tried adding a delay with setcenter but that did not work either.

Thanks in advance for anyone out there who can offer up any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use separate function call parameters:

```
local function mapmarker( event )
    myMap:addMarker( currentXlatitude, currentXlongitude)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Schollii, I tried the format you suggest as well but it won't work. Any other suggestions?